# " $ rospack depends beginner_tutorials" error

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, tutorial, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight dump of console output:

```
ImportError: No module named rosdep2.rospack
ImportError: No module named rosdep2.rospack
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
$ env | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/lunar/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/perove/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/lunar/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/perove/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=lunar
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/lunar/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269315/%22-$-rospack-depends-beginner_tutorials%22-error/) by [PerOve](https://answers.ros.org/users/31656/perove/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-22**:
This is not really a question. Please see our [Support Guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29).

**Comment by [PerOve](https://answers.ros.org/users/31656/perove/) on 2017-08-22**:
What is the cause of this error.?
I have subsequently re-installed a new kinetic instance in a virtual machine ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.6 (default). It appears to run now. I previously ran with 2.7 environment (Anaconda).. this now gives the same error. What Python should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lunar only supports Python 2.7 (see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019) and (fi) #q269143). If you want to use Anaconda, you'll have to make sure that all ROS Python packages have been installed for that as Anaconda does not use the default / system Python packages. That is most likely why you are getting that error.

There have been quite some questions and answers about Anaconda posted/resolved recently, so a search should provide some pointers.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0